# Asp.net session when the user is unauthenticated

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables

I have a webforms asp.net page that displays search results. I would like to store the search results in session until the user performs a new search. User can search on the website even if unauthenticated. I have two web servers behind the F5 load balancer. The load balancer maintains sticky session irrespective of web app authentication.

So my question is, am I doing anything wrong in this process. should I not be storing search results in session if the user is not logged in. Is there anything wrong with this approach.

Comment: As a lot if things on life and programming depends._ Do your system need it like this, like a requirement? If the answers is _Yes_ then shouldn't be any problem with that

Comment: Thank you William for quickly responding. This is one of the legacy app that we maintain and will be replaced by a new web app in future. We have an issue where users are complaining about pagination, filtering being too slow on the search page. The way it is currently implemented the page makes trip back and forth to the database everytime user clicks on page 2 or 3 etc. Also similar thing is implemented with filters. So to get an improved performance without changing too much logic on the page, we resorted to this option.

Comment: If what you're taking in mind is the fact of in a _near future_ change the web app you should do it for new technologies (.NET MVC or Core) that could solve the problem of data being too slow, but basically you can take that route of the session, tough the improvement wouldn't be that much, other ways is improving the consults to the DataBase

Comment: In general, storing data in the session for unauthenticated users should not cause you issues. In this particular case, I'd personally be concerned about memory usage; does re-running the search each time incur much overhead?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1078662/How-to-implement-Paging-in-ASP-NET-at-SQL-Query-Le